# Convert XFDL files to HTML?

Tags: html, xfdl

If I have some forms in Extensible Forms Description Language ([XFDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Forms_Description_Language)) format, is there a good way render them as HTML? Someone hasn't been kind enough to create an free XSLT file for doing this transformation, have they? What might my other options me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a significant amount of work required if you are intending to render in html as well as reproduce any "logic" (via conversion to javascript) that may be inherent in the XFDL form, such as XFDL computes or XPath functions.

There is a product by IBM called Lotus Forms Server that includes a component called Webform Server that renders XFDL in html, yet also runs all of the application logic that may be embedded in the form by making ajax calls back to the server as needed (and occasionally round-tripping if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Doing it yourself. Sorry, learning XSLT could be an interesting experience and is best left to be done yourself.